# Why does this operator overloading work?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I am trying to learn C++ OOP concepts through an online tutorial where I encountered a code snippet illustrating operator overloading.

The code is shown below:

```
class MyClass{
int var;
public:
    Myclass(int value=0){
    var = value;
    }

    Myclass operator+(Myclass &obj){
    Myclass newobj;
    newobj.var = this->var + obj.var;
    return newobj;
    }
};
```

Suppose I call the operator in the main function like so:

```
int main(){
...
obj3 = obj2 + obj1;
...
}
```

During earlier tutorials on Classes, I read about why copy constructors require all parameters to be passed by reference since they themselves are the definition of how to copy two class objects. So, as far as I understand, copy constructors are a must when one has to copy objects of a class.

In the above code snippet, it appears to me that the compiler will try to "copy" the values of newobj onto the L_value in the main() function (obj3). But how is this possible without a copy constructor defined. Have I misunderstood something here?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The compiler will define a default copy constructor for you.

Comment: In certain cases the compiler will generate a copy ctor and copy assign operator for you.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577907/default-copy-constructor

Comment: Operator overloading has nothing to do with OOP concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-declared_copy_constructor

If you are using standard C++ 2003 or older copy constructor is always implicitly defined (generated by compiler) for any class `T` unless:

- T has non-static data members that cannot be copied (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);
- T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be copied (has deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);
- T has direct or virtual base class with a deleted or inaccessible destructor;

If you are using standard C++ 2011 or newer copy constructor is always implicitly defined (generated by compiler) for any class `T` unless:

- T has non-static data members that cannot be copied (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);
- T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be copied (has deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);
- T has direct or virtual base class with a deleted or inaccessible destructor;
- T has a user-defined move constructor or move assignment operator;
- T is a union and has a variant member with non-trivial copy constructor;
- T has a data member of rvalue reference type.

Also keep in mind that

```
a = b;
```

is not primarily calling copy-constructor but **copy-assignment**. That in turn is also implicitly defined (auto-generated) if your class if *suitable*.

For details see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator